# How to have two Firebase (Firestore) database for debug and produciton in andorid?

Tags: android, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing an android app. I want to keep two separate databases for my app. One is for Production and another is for debugging and testing.
how should I achieve this?
assume that I'm using Firebase OTP auth, Cloud Firestore and Google Cloud Messaging services in my app.
When I try to create two projects, I got an error that, "The custom token corresponds to a different audience. [ App ID does not match requested project. ]"
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You're supposed to create different Firebase projects, one for each environment you want to test.  The data for each one is completely independent of each other, and you have to configure your app to point to the project you want to use at any given moment.

Please [read the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#support_multiple_environments_in_your_android_application) for more information.

Comment: I already saw the link that you give. But my problem is when I create separate project, my Firebase otp auth is not working without SHA1. when i tried to add the SHA1 to the project it say "already an app with SHA1 exists"

Comment: You can't have the same app with the same application id and SHA-1 added to multiple projects.  You need to either use a different application id or different SHA-1 with each one.  The combination of application id and SHA-1 must be unique among all projects.

Comment: You'll need to create a new signing key.  It's almost certainly easier to just configure your build to use different application ids instead of trying to use different signing keys for everything.

Comment: so you are saying that changing the package name (app id)is easy. right?

Comment: You should be able to find some options by doing web searches.